# Transcendental elements in K with $\text{char}(K)=p>0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, transcendental-numbers, transcendence-theory

> Let $\Omega$ be an algebraically closed field with characteristic $p>0$, a subfield $K\subset \Omega$ and $L:=K(\tau^p, \eta^p)$. If $\tau$ is transcendental over $K$ and $\eta$ is  transcendental over $K(\tau)$, prove that:
>
> $1)$ $[K(\tau, \eta):L]=p^2$;
>
> $2)$ $[L(\zeta):L]=p$ for any $\zeta\in K(\tau,\eta)-L$;
>
> $3)$ $K(\tau, \eta)|L$ has no primitive element.

Here's where I'm at:

$1)$ It is clear that $\eta, ..., \eta^{p-1}\in K(\tau^p, \eta)-L$ and because $\eta$ is transcendent over $K(\tau)$, we have that $1,\eta, ..., \eta^{p-1}$ are $L$-linear independent, so $[K(\tau^p, \eta):L]=p$. Analogously, $\tau, ..., \tau^{p-1}\in K(\tau, \eta)-K(\tau^p, \eta)$ and by transcendecy of $\eta$ over $K(\tau)$, we get linear independency, so $[K(\tau, \eta):L]=p^2$.

$3)$ If there existed $\alpha\in K(\tau, \eta)$ with $K(\tau, \eta)=L(\alpha)$, we would have from $2)$ that $[L(\alpha):L]=p$ (absurd, because $[K(\tau, \eta):L]=p^2$).

$2)$ this is where I'm stuck, and I don't know what the characteristic $p>0$ has to do with anything.

Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: it fails with $\tau = \eta$, so you mean $\eta$ transcendental in $K(\tau)$ ?

Comment: Write again in the statement that characteristic is greater than $0$ and that  $\eta$ and $\tau$ are distinct (just distinct? or $K$-linearly independent?)

Comment: Is it $p$ the characteristic? you do have to say it!  Edit your post, please

Comment: If characteristic is $0$ $\eta^k$ with $k=1,2,...,p-1$ has no sense.

Comment: in deed, this question needed some adjustments. Just edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\zeta \in K(\tau,\eta) - L$.
Then there exists an $f \in L(X,Y)$ such that $\zeta = f(\tau,\eta)$.
We obtain:
$$
\zeta^p = f(\tau,\eta)^p = f(\tau^p,\eta^p) \in L
$$
by applying Frobenius.
This shows $[L(\zeta):L] \leq p$.
Now $L(\zeta)/L$ is a proper field extension, so $[L(\zeta):L] > 1$ and since $[L(\zeta):L]\mid p^2$ by 1) we have $[L(\zeta):L] = p$.